# Extracting expressions from an f-string

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I am writing a python tool that both performs static python code analysis and performs some automated rewriting of that code (like expanding wildcard imports). Part of what I need this tool to do is to extract out all expressions that occur within f-strings, ideally formatted in exactly the same way they appear in the code.

```
f'{a+b} {c   *d}'  -> ['a+b', 'c   *d']
f'{int("3" * 2):d}'  -> ['int("3" * 2)']
```

The best I could come up with was a solution that returns the expressions, but without preserving the original formatting:

```
import ast  # requires python3.9 for ast.unparse()
def extract(s):
    values = ast.parse(f"f'{s}'").body[0].value.values
    fvalues = [v for v in values if isinstance(v, ast.FormattedValue)]
    return [ast.unparse(t.value) for t in fvalues]

>>> extract('{a+b} {c   *d}')
['a + b', 'c * d']
>>> extract('{int("3" * 2):d}')
["int('3' * 2)"]
```

For the purpose of my tool, I can get some value out of this, but I would really prefer to retain the original formatting. Is there a clean solution for this, asides from replicating the [intricate f-string parsing logic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) that exists in the implementation of the python interpreter? (Where exactly can I find that logic anyways? `Python-ast.h` doesn't seem to house it.)

The [redbaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module generally promises to parse python code into an abstract syntax tree that retains formatting, but it does not appear to support f-strings.

Comment: btw you might be interested in https://github.com/oughtinc/fvalues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) has a "See also" box at the bottom with some options that should help you, including:

- [asttokens](https://asttokens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)
- [LibCST](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

(Some of the others might help too, but I couldn't tell from a brief look.)

Comment: Thanks, LibCST seems like a better supported version of redbaron to me!